# Upload img path to db codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload the path of an image when it has been uploaded.

The form currently sends the file to the file system with no problem when I comment out the model towards the bottom.

**The controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('uploaderview', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './upl0d/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';      //2mb
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('uploaderview', $error);
        } else {
            ## Insert into filesystem.
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            ## load the success page.
            $this->load->view('uploadsuccess', $data);
            ## Insert into db
            ## then insert the img name into the database
            this->load->model('uploadermodel');
            $this->uploadermodel->uploadcoupon();               
        }
    }
}
```

**And a model:**

```
<?php
class Uploadermodel extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function uploadcoupon(){
        $uploadFileName = $upload_data['orig_name'];
        $currentDt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $data = array('fileNameUploaded'=>$uploadFileName,'date'=>$currentDt);
        $this->db->insert('Coupon', $data); 
    }
}   
?>
```

When I include the model, I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 36
```

Here is  line 36 of the controller:

```
this->load->model('uploadermodel');
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Silly of me. Thanks Pekka

Comment: The problem is the variable $uploadFileName is null or empty. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is `$upload_data` supposed to come from? You're not passing it from the other function

Comment: If you view: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html it uses it there . Which function should it be passed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CodeTalk - have a look at your other question for more complete details:

[Pass Data from Controller to Model Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676864/pass-data-from-controller-to-model-codeigniter)

But you need to pass

```
 $this->uploadermodel->uploadcoupon($my_insert_data);
```

and again:

```
uploadcoupon($my_insert_data)
```